# How do I add an html editor to my ASP.net project?

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, html-editor

I've searched through my toolbox in Visual Studio and I can't see this option anywhere in it.  Basically, I have a page that I want to add an HTML editor on.  In case I am using the incorrect term, here is a picture of what I would like to add:

[image]

Essentially, I need this text editor to format what is written in it to HTML.  I am using ASP.NET web forms page that has a Master Page.  I have read about TinyMCE but I am not really sure if this is what I want?  Or how to add it to my project in Visual Studio.  Is there an equivalent in the toolbox?

This is my code so far:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages    /Columns.Master" CodeBehind="NoticeDetail.aspx.vb" Inherits="...NoticeDetail" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="headmeta" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="headCustomScriptsCSS" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="cpMainContent" runat="server">
<h1>Notice Details</h1>

<!-- this is where I want to add the editor -->

</asp:Content>
```

Thanks!

Edit:

I need something published by Microsoft.  I am not able to use any 3rd party software unfortunately.  If anyone knows of any Microsoft tools, that would be ideal!

Answer (score 6):

I'm not aware of any controls that ship as part of .NET that allow you to edit HTML. But, Microsoft does provide the Ajax Control Toolkit, which includes the [HTML Editor Extender](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx). Basically you just tell the Extender what you want it to include and tell it what TextBox to "extend" to support HTML.

Example.

```
 <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" 
            TargetControlID="TextBox1" DisplaySourceTab="true" 
            runat="server"/>
            <Toolbar> 
                <ajaxToolkit:Undo />
                <ajaxToolkit:Redo />
                <ajaxToolkit:Bold />
                <ajaxToolkit:Italic />
                <ajaxToolkit:Underline />
                <ajaxToolkit:StrikeThrough />
                <ajaxToolkit:Subscript />
                <ajaxToolkit:Superscript />
                <ajaxToolkit:JustifyLeft />
                <ajaxToolkit:JustifyCenter />
                <ajaxToolkit:JustifyRight />
                <ajaxToolkit:JustifyFull />
                <ajaxToolkit:InsertOrderedList />
                <ajaxToolkit:InsertUnorderedList />
                <ajaxToolkit:CreateLink />
                <ajaxToolkit:UnLink />
                <ajaxToolkit:RemoveFormat />
                <ajaxToolkit:SelectAll />
                <ajaxToolkit:UnSelect />
                <ajaxToolkit:Delete />
                <ajaxToolkit:Cut />
                <ajaxToolkit:Copy />
                <ajaxToolkit:Paste />
                <ajaxToolkit:BackgroundColorSelector />
                <ajaxToolkit:ForeColorSelector />
                <ajaxToolkit:FontNameSelector />
                <ajaxToolkit:FontSizeSelector />
                <ajaxToolkit:Indent />
                <ajaxToolkit:Outdent />
                <ajaxToolkit:InsertHorizontalRule />
                <ajaxToolkit:HorizontalSeparator />
                <ajaxToolkit:InsertImage />
            </Toolbar>
        </ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

From the documentation:

> The HtmlEditorExtender is an ASP.NET AJAX Control that enables you to
>   extend the standard ASP.NET TextBox control with support for rich
>   formatting. For example, the HtmlEditorExtender enables users to apply
>   bold, italic, underline, subscript, superscript, and different
>   foreground and background color to text.

You'll need to add the Ajax Control Toolkit to your project in order to make use of it. I like to use NuGet to add libraries when possible, [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit/7.1213.0) it is on NuGet.

I have not used TinyMCE, but I've heard good things about it. Yes, you can use it in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the **RadEditor** that is part of the **Telerik ASP.NET AJAX Controls**? It really is one of the best HTML/Content editors out there for .NET:
http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx

If the RadEditor is out of budget scope, then perhaps you should consider implementing the **CKEditor**?

- [ckeditor in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906407/ckeditor-in-asp-net)
- http://ckeditor.com

Comment: However, this costs $1000 at a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax HTMLEditorExtender control can be used as text editor to format what is written in HTML. Here are steps to add ajax HMTLEditorExtender control in webform -

http://newapputil.blogspot.in/2014/06/adding-ajax-htmleditorextender-control.html

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps:

1. Add EditorLite.vb and Inherits AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.Editor

   ```
    Imports System.Collections
    Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

    Namespace CustomEditor
    Public Class EditorLite
    Inherits AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.Editor

    Protected Overrides Sub FillBottomToolbar()
        BottomToolbar.Buttons.Add(New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.DesignMode)
        BottomToolbar.Buttons.Add(New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.HtmlMode)
        BottomToolbar.Buttons.Add(New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.PreviewMode)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub FillTopToolbar()
        Dim options As Collection(Of AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.SelectOption)
        Dim optiond As AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.SelectOption
        TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.Bold)
        TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.Italic)
        TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.Underline)
        TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.HorizontalSeparator)
        Dim FixedForeColor As AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.FixedForeColor = New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.FixedForeColor
        TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(FixedForeColor)
        Dim ForeColorSelector As AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.ForeColorSelector = New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.ForeColorSelector
        FixedForeColor.ID = "FixedForeColor"
        ForeColorSelector.FixedColorButtonId = "FixedForeColor"
        TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(ForeColorSelector)
        TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.ForeColorClear)
        TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.HorizontalSeparator)
        Dim fontName As AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.FontName = New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.FontName
        TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(fontName)
        options = fontName.Options
        optiond = New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.SelectOption
        optiond.Value = ""
        optiond.Text = ""
        options.Add(optiond)
        optiond = New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.SelectOption
        optiond.Value = "arial,helvetica,sans-serif"
        optiond.Text = "Arial"
        options.Add(optiond)
        optiond = New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.SelectOption
        optiond.Value = "courier new,courier,monospace"
        optiond.Text = "Courier New"
        options.Add(optiond)
        optiond = New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.SelectOption
        optiond.Value = "georgia,times new roman,times,serif"
        optiond.Text = "Georgia"
        options.Add(optiond)
        optiond = New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.SelectOption
        optiond.Value = "tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif"
        optiond.Text = "Tahoma"
        options.Add(optiond)
        optiond = New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.SelectOption
        optiond.Value = "times new roman,times,serif"
        optiond.Text = "Times New Roman"
        options.Add(optiond)
        optiond = New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.SelectOption
        optiond.Value = "verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif"
        optiond.Text = "Verdana"
        options.Add(optiond)
        optiond = New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.SelectOption
        optiond.Value = "impact"
        optiond.Text = "Impact"
        options.Add(optiond)
        optiond = New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.SelectOption
        optiond.Value = "wingdings"
        optiond.Text = "WingDings"
        options.Add(optiond)
        TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.HorizontalSeparator)
        Dim fontSize As AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.FontSize = New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.FontSize
        TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(fontSize)
        options = fontSize.Options
        optiond = New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.SelectOption
        optiond.Value = ""
        optiond.Text = ""
        options.Add(optiond)
        optiond = New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.SelectOption
        optiond.Value = "8pt"
        optiond.Text = "1 ( 8 pt)"
        options.Add(optiond)
        optiond = New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.SelectOption
        optiond.Value = "10pt"
        optiond.Text = "2 (10 pt)"
        options.Add(optiond)
        optiond = New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.SelectOption
        optiond.Value = "12pt"
        optiond.Text = "3 (12 pt)"
        options.Add(optiond)
        optiond = New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.SelectOption
        optiond.Value = "14pt"
        optiond.Text = "4 (14 pt)"
        options.Add(optiond)
        optiond = New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.SelectOption
        optiond.Value = "18pt"
        optiond.Text = "5 (18 pt)"
        options.Add(optiond)
        optiond = New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.SelectOption
        optiond.Value = "24pt"
        optiond.Text = "6 (24 pt)"
        options.Add(optiond)
        optiond = New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.SelectOption
        optiond.Value = "36pt"
        optiond.Text = "7 (36 pt)"
        options.Add(optiond)
        TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.HorizontalSeparator)
        TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(New AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.RemoveStyles)
    End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class LiteNoBottom
    Inherits EditorLite

    Protected Overrides Sub FillBottomToolbar()

    End Sub
    End Class
    End Namespace
   ```

Step 2: Consume LiteNoBottom in source code:

```
<%@ Register Namespace="CustomEditor" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<cc1:LiteNoBottom ID="Editor1" runat="server" CssClass="Editor" />
```